# Drop-down menu flashes, temporarily opens on page load on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue with a jQuery-driven accordion drop-down menu when viewed on a mobile device. The problem is when viewed in either portrait or landscape, the drop-down menu quickly flashes (temporarily opens revealing all the links) upon page load, almost flickering. Refresh the page, it does the same thing.

Also, when viewed in landscape mode, the tabs in the drop-down menu wiggle up and down briefly when you click on them.

I'm not sure if this is a jQuery/JS issue or maybe there is something I need to do with CSS? I've done some research and cannot find a solution to this problem.

Can someone please take a look at the example here: http://clients.iconcw.com and let me know how to fix this problem?

Thanks very much.